# ANDing in JOIN Condition Using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I recently ran into some SQL code that looks like this

```
SELECT
    a.Id,
    b.Id,
    c.Id,
    d.Id,
    b.Name,
    d.Occupation,
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = b.Id
JOIN TableC c ON b.Id = c.Id AND b.Name = a.Name
JOIN tableD d ON c.Id = d.Id AND c.Occupation = d.Occupation
```

I've never used ANDs inside JOINs like this in a corresponding LINQ query (for context, I use the Entity Framework and LINQ for all of my queries). I usually put all my ANDs inside there where clause like this:

```
var query = from a in dbContext.TableA
            join b in dbContext.TableB on a.Id equals b.Id
            join c in dbContext.TableC on b.Id equals c.Id
            join d in dbContext.TableD on c.Id equals d.Id
            where b.Name = a.Name
            where c.Occupation = d.Occupation
            select new
            {
                AId = a.Id,
                BId = b.Id,
                CId = c.Id,
                DId = d.Id,
                BName = b.Name,
                DOccupation = d.Occupation,
            };
```

What technique can I use to get my LINQ query to match the SQL statement above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on multiple properties by constructing anonymous types from your properties like this:

```
var query = from a in dbContext.TableA
            join b in dbContext.TableB on new { a.Id, a.Name } equals new { b.Id, b.Name }
            join c in dbContext.TableC on b.Id equals c.Id
            join d in dbContext.TableD on new { c.Id, c.Occupation } equals new { d.Id, d.Occupation }
            select new
            {
                AId = a.Id,
                BId = b.Id,
                CId = c.Id,
                DId = d.Id,
                BName = b.Name,
                DOccupation = d.Occupation,
            };
```

Note that the name, order, and datatype of each property in the anonymous types need to be the same on both sides of the `equals` in order for this to work. Otherwise they would be two different anonymous types and would not be equatable.